# Create Service with Symfony2

Tags: php, service, symfony

Using symfony2 I am following [this documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/service_container.html) to create and use a service for performing a general task.

I have it almost done, but I have one problem yet (surely due to some misunderstanding on service containers in Symfony2.

The class is something like this:

```
class MyClass{
    private $myProperty;

    public funciton performSomethingGeneral{
        return $theResult;
    }
}
```

Now, in my config.yml:

```
services:
    myService:
        class: Acme\MyBundle\Service\MyClass
        arguments: [valueForMyProperty]
```

Finally, in my controller:

```
$myService = $this -> container -> get('myService');
```

After that line, When I inspect `$myService`, I still see $myService -> $myProperty as uninitialized.

There is something I am not getting properly. What else do I have to do to get the property initialized and ready to use with a previously configured value in `config.yml`? And how would I set more than one property?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`arguments` from your yml file are passed to the constructor of your service, so you should handle it there.

```
services:
    myService:
        class: Acme\MyBundle\Service\MyClass
        arguments: [valueForMyProperty, otherValue]
```

and php:

```
class MyClass{
    private $myProperty;
    private $otherProperty;

    public funciton __construct($property1, $property2){
         $this->myProperty = $property1;   
         $this->otherProperty = $property2;   
    }
}
```