# Multiple Actions in one Controller - Symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony, controller, submission

i have a complex form. This form is created in the controller A.
All actions, like: edit, add, load, index 
are in the controller A defined and the method actionIndex is essential for all other requests.

Like this schema:

```
public class controllerA  {


function actionIndex(Requerst r){

    r.handleRequest();

    if ($form->get('index')->isClicked()){
      // Index Action
    }
    if ($form->get('add')->isClicked()){
      $this->actionAdd();
    }
    // ...
}
function actionAdd(){}

}

}
```

How do i seperate the requests in different controllers?
Actually it doesnt feel good.

Here my actual code of the controller:
http://pastebin.com/HuXhV37q

Comment: Are your forms based on an entity? If so, most of the form can be handled by Symfony itself ( http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#forms-and-doctrine ). 
Otherwise, I would suggest that you write separate classes that will handle the form, so not separate controllers.

Comment: that are mixed forms the whole form has many entities. how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have skimmed through your code and I speak german so I understand it.

It would be too much to cover here so I just give you some "keywords".

Outsource business logic from controllers to symfony services to keep the controllers **light**. ($zusaetzeArray etc.)

Create Entities and FormTypes for the form data if it makes sense economically.

Create multiple controller actions with corresponding routes for the different form states.

> Symfony2 Service: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13099900/982075